# C# optimization - arrays / lists of value types and the stack (gaming)

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm working on a game and am in the middle of a bit of AI number crunching and I want to optimize the code as much as I can. I have several structs in my code like Circle, Vector, etc. I want to reduce to a minimum the load on the GC as a result of this code since it will run many times a second and in each invocation will generate several large arrays and perform a lot of computations.

My question is, if I have a small method that can "return" multiple value types (i.e intersection of circle and vector, etc), what is the most performant way to transfer its result back to the main method?

I can think of a few ways to do it:

- Return an array of the results i.e Vector[ ]
- Return a List<Vector>
- Pass in a List<Vector>
- Any other way..?

What would be the best strategy to avoid a lot of small unnecessary objects / arrays on the heap that the GC then has to collect?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem? If not, then how do you know what part of the code to optimize?

Comment: Actually, I'd be focusing on the "generate several large arrays" step - can those arrays be re-used, for example

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm trying to pre-empt a problem here (I know, premature ... root of all evil :-) ) but my question was more general about this particular type of situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're in a situation where:

- You're calling this method very frequently
- You'll always be dealing with the same size of collection (or similar, at least)
- You don't need the previous results by the time you next call it

... then you *may* be able to improve performance by repeatedly passing in the same array (or `List<T>`) and modifying it. On the other hand, you should absolutely measure performance *before* making any changes. You should also determine what's going to be "good enough" so you don't bend your code away from the most natural design any more than you have to.

Comment: +1 for modifying, always try to re-use objects instead of destroy and create. If a space invader goes off the bottom of the screen, move him to the top instead of destroying him and creating a new one.

Comment: Wow, lots of great answers so quickly, thank you all :-)

Yes I can re-use arrays and lists but that of course makes the small methods a bit more awkward than say return Vector[] so this is why I asked. But if re-using is the way to go I can definitely do that.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot of the type of your data passed, most times games use structs for vectors, intersection-data, etc...

When the data are structs you should avoid `List<T>` and passing per value because the data is copied then. But this depends a lot on the code, sometimes passing per value might be faster, sometimes not. I would make some performance tests. You can use this method for simple tests without a profiler:

```
public static Int64 MeasureTime(Action myAction)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    myAction();
    stopWatch.Stop();
    return stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

When dealing with structs it might be always a good way to use `out` or `ref`.

### More informations

*All this situations may not cause a performance issue, they are just to explain best practices i learned when working with structs. To determine if `ref` and `out` are useful in each case you should make a performance test.*

`ref` **is used to avoid such situations:**

```
Vector input = new Vector(x, y, z);
input = ModifyVector(input); // This line causes copies of the input vector and it's slow
```

The performance hit here depends a lot of the size of the `Vector` class, it's not a good practice to use the following method everytime. When returning a simple Int32 it's not necessary and should not be used to keep the code readable.

**Right way:**

```
Vector input = new Vector(x, y, z);
ModifyVector(ref input);
```

Of course the `ref` keyword could be used to make methods faster which return nothing, but this methods must take care about the data passed to them and should avoid modifing them. The speed benefit could be more than 50% in some situations ( I have a high-performance vector library and i tested many cases ).

`out` **is used to avoid such situations:**

```
Ray ray = ...;
CollisionData data = CastRay(ref ray); // Note the ref here to pass the Ray which contains 6 floats
```

CollisionData contains at least the point where it hits the ground and a normal. When using `out` here to get the result it should be much faster.

**Right way:**

```
Ray ray = ...;
CollisionData data;
CastRay(ref ray, out data);
```

**When using arrays..**

..you should know that a array is already a reference and you don't need the `ref` or `out` keyword to handle them. But when working with structs you should know that you are not holding references of the structs in your array. So when modifing a value of a array you can use `ref myArray[0]` to pass the value to a method and modify the struct at index zero in place without copying it. Also avoid to create new instances of them.

Comment: I was thinking of out/ref but my problem was that in some of these cases there is a variable number of results (for example intersection between a line and a circle, polygon and circle, etc).

Comment: @Amir yes, but if you know the *maximum* number you can create an array. then access by index; `arr[i].SomeValue` doesn't need to copy the struct to read the value - using a list ***does*** copy

Comment: @MarcGravell I see so `ref Vector[]` is better than passing in a `List<Vector>` which in turn is better than `return new Vector[]` (as a rule of thumb)?

Comment: @AmirAbiri you only need the `ref` if you are going to reassign the array; just a `Vector[]` should suffice normally.

Comment: @AmirAbiri Arrays already references so passing them to a method should cost nothing. But when working with a list you are copying the Vector each time when accessing it ( List works with indexer ). I updating my post for more clarity.

Comment: Eek - of course I was being daft. Is there no inlining of the list indexer?

Comment: @AmirAbiri There could be inlining but this won't prevent the CLR from copying the struct because this is the behaviour the user expects. I hope my examples help a bit.

Comment: Yes but if the indexer is inlined than there would be no difference between an array and a list? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AmirAbiri No, this would change the behaviour of the indexer which may be expected by some ppl. Inlined methods are not modified in their behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is your platform/framework (XNA?), but I have encountered a problem with GC under Windows Phone 7 (7.5 got generational GC, but haven't test it). To avoid so called freezes of GC I made a collection where I pre-load all necessary data into Dictionary.

but first measure measure measure.